# How can I recursively unarchive all files that are bzipped2?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, scripting, archive

I have a folder. In this folder I have a lot of other folders. In folders I have bzip files and non-bzip. How to unarchieve all bzip2 files in same directory where they are ?

Answer (score 1):

If your bzip2 files have the standard bz2 extension, try this:

```
find some_dir_with_bzip2_files -name *.bz2 -exec bunzip2 {} \;
```

Full example:

```
$ tree a
a
├── b
│   ├── d
│   ├── file.four
│   └── file.three
├── c
│   └── e
│       ├── file.seven.bz2
│       └── file.six.bz2
├── file.one.bz2
└── file.two.bz2

$ find a -name *.bz2 -exec bunzip2 {} \;

$ tree a
a
├── b
│   ├── d
│   ├── file.four
│   └── file.three
├── c
│   └── e
│       ├── file.seven
│       └── file.six
├── file.one
└── file.two
```